# What means new page is loaded via an event or is done by sending a native event?

Tags: java, selenium, click

I read information about method click of interface WebElement, but not clearly understand what mean such statement "If click() causes a new page to be loaded via an event or is done by sending a native event"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full javadoc:

> Click this element. If this causes a new page to load, this method
>   will attempt to block until the page has loaded. At this point, you
>   should discard all references to this element and any further
>   operations performed on this element will throw a
>   StaleElementReferenceException unless you know the element and the
>   page will still be present. If click() causes a new page to be loaded
>   via an event or is done by sending a native event then the method will
>   *not* wait for it to be loaded and the caller should verify that a new page has been loaded.

This means that click() is a blocking call if a new request in the browser is issued. And returns when the page is loaded.

click() is not a blocking call when it executes some javascript that loads the new page (or parts of it) (ajax). In this case you have to use WebDriverWait and wait for some css-classes / ids / text to appear.